# Converting "% faster" to "X times speedup"

Tags: word-problem

I'm confusing myself over a rather pedantic math question. I'm comparing two simulation's runtimes (measured in seconds). I want to know how many times faster is simulation A compared to simulation B.

Normally, I report the result as a percentage, e.g., simulation A is 50% faster than simulation B. To get this percentage, I can simply divide $$t_A / t_B$$. 50% faster is equivalent to "1 times speedup". I'm wondering what is the equation to get this speedup number on less nice numbers?

Comment: It's subtle. Does this answer your question? [What does "X% faster" mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27202/what-does-x-faster-mean)

Comment: I would say $A$ needs $\left(\frac{t_a}{t_b}-1\right)\cdot 100\%$ more time than $B$.  I am cautious about using velocity/speed here.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup#Using_execution_times), A using $50\%$ less time than B would be a $2$x speedup, not "1 times". Calculated from dividing the two run times, and assuming the same amount of workload.

Answer (score 1):

To say a value $x$ is $p\%$ greater than a value $y$ means that $\dfrac {x-y}y \times 100\% = p\%$. That fraction can also be expressed as $\left(\dfrac xy - 1\right)$. In this case, you are comparing the speeds to accomplish the task, which will be $x = \dfrac 1{t_A}$ and $y = \dfrac 1{t_b}$, so $$\dfrac xy = \dfrac{\dfrac 1{t_A}}{\dfrac 1{t_B}} = \frac {t_B}{t_A}$$ and the answer to your question is

- Simulation A is $\left(\dfrac {t_B}{t_A} - 1\right)\times 100\%$ faster than Simulation B.

In particular A will be $50\%$ faster than B if $t_B = (1.5)t_A$